# Arrange outer nodes as square

Tags: graphviz, neato

Considering the following graph:

```
graph {
  node[shape=square];
  A [color=olivedrab4 /* pos="0,0!" */ ];
  B [color=orange     /* pos="0,3!" */ ];
  C [color=royalblue  /* pos="5,3!" */ ];
  D [color=orangered  /* pos="5,0!" */ ];

  node[shape=circle];
  u -- v -- w -- {x y}

  A -- u;
  B -- v;
  C -- y;
  D -- x;

}
```

which `neato` renders like this:

[image: freely arranged graph]

is there a way to fix `[A-D]` in the corners of a square and have the subgraph `[u-y]` neatly laid out between?

Note: Uncommenting the position hints in the code above yields the following, unsatisfactory result:

[image: position hinted graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `fdp` instead of `neato` and uncomment the position hints:

```
fdp -Tpng corners.gv -o corners.png
```

[image: graphviz output]

Or, if you want to use `neato`, add some initial pos attribute to the other nodes, too, and place them in the middle:

```
node[shape=circle, pos="2.5,1.5"];
```

(no exclamation mark after the coordinates).

Output is almost the same:

[image: graphviz output - neato]